# rodbc. connection error

Tags: r, oracle11g, rodbc

I am getting this error

```
Error in typesR2DBMS[[driver]] <<- value[c("double", "integer",
 "character", : cannot change value of locked binding for 'typesR2DBMS'
```

when I try to connect it to the oracle DB. I am using RODBC and RODM libraries to connect to the oracle server. I can successfully test my connection on DSN. 
Can somebody also tell what does this error means? I have tried to search it at many places but mainly people are recommending to use ORE library instead. But I want to try RODM library only.

Comment: Possible solution [here](https://forums.oracle.com/message/11030499)

Comment: I have seen that forum. It also tells you to install ORE library. If we use ORe library then we need to install it on the server side too and I don't have the admin rights for it. Also, I am very curious to know the solution for this error